# How to send Dart Map Objects over Web Sockets to PHP Server?

Tags: php, dart, flutter

**Background**
I am working on a dating app and it needs to have a realtime messaging feature, I am working on a messaging feature for the first time. So far I have only been able to connect my app clients to my web socket server to send and receive Strings

**What I Want**
I want to send JSON objects over web sockets so this way I can send my custom Message class to another client and also because my PHP server will use the user id from JSON object for storing messages to database.

**Problem**
When I try sending myMessage.toJson() in web socket channel then it gives an error, that it is not a string, so I used jsonEncode(myMessage.toJson()) to convert JSON object to string, it doesn't give an error in the client app anymore, but instead I try running the following code in PHP but it doesn't work

```
$x = (array) json_decode($msg, true);
echo $x['message_seen']; //Should print 'true' or 'false' //Prints nothing
```

**Here's a sample of the JSON object I send**

```
{id: 889, from_user_profile: {id: null, name: null, birthday: null, gender: null, join_date: null, occupation: null, education: null, height: null, age: null, photo_url: null, longitude: null, user_status: null, latitude: null, showcase_photos_url: null, distance_in_km: null, spoken_languages: null, premium_points: null, is_facebook_linked: 1, is_setup: 1, has_premium: 1}, to_user_profile: {id: null, name: null, birthday: null, gender: null, join_date: null, occupation: null, education: null, height: null, age: null, photo_url: null, longitude: null, user_status: null, latitude: null, showcase_photos_url: null, distance_in_km: null, spoken_languages: null, premium_points: null, is_facebook_linked: 1, is_setup: 1, has_premium: 1}, message_content: Test Message, timestamp: null, message_seen: false, message_type: Casual Meetup}
```

Comment: did you check [json_last_error()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to be sure that you're actually decoding the json right?

Comment: Yes, '0', 'No error'

Comment: Can you post a sample of the actual json that you are sending as well?